# Deactivating a UIButton

Tags: iphone, xcode

When I click a button for more than half a second, the button turns blue (being activated). Then, if I drag my touch out side the button, it is still activated and if i release my touch it activates my action.

How can I deactivate a UIButton when dragging outside?

Thanks.

Comment: What mmc says. It sounds like you've hooked up the touchUpOutside event instead of touchUpInside.

Comment: I assure you i didn't :)

Answer (score 4):

The event you have wired up to the UIButton should be "touchUpInside"

This will have the behavior you desire.

Comment: It is wired up to "touchUpInside". But in my case, where the button is in a scrollView, when i touch the button and drag it out, the scrolling is disrupted.

Comment: Ah, the scrollview is a huge piece of the equation, and you left it out of the question!

Comment: :) sorry about that. Didn't think it is that important. Any suggestions?

Comment: Frankly, I don't have a clue... but dragging your touch outside the button is likely being interpreted as a scroll, or something like that. There are several questions on here about UIButtons in UIScrollViews, dragging, and some seem similar to your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UIButton+UIScrollView